DefaultAzureCredential not working on an Azure Arc enabled Windows Server
I have an arc enabled Windows Server 2022.
Im using DefaultAzureCredential and trying to use the Azure assigned managed identity to Authenticate to Azure key vault (and also azure storage at some stage)
I've populated the environment variable AZURE_CLIENT_ID + AZURE_TENANT_ID with the Id of this managed identity (object id of the managed identity shown to me in Entra ID) and you can see the other related environment variables:

But on starting the windows service I just get:

AuthenticationFailedException. User assigned managed identity is not supported by the detected managed identity environment
SO confused - I thought this was supported in Arc enabled servers? If this is not the way to do it in the Porgram startup, then how is it done? Im trying to not use the AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET
The code to get the secrets is just basic:
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(vaultUrl), new DefaultAzureCredential());
var secretList = client.GetPropertiesOfSecrets();


Does the managed identity have the Key Vault Secrets User or Key Vault Contributor role assigned to the Key Vault?

May I know whether you tried to add AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET into environment variable? Does the issue still exist if you added the secret?

It works with a secret @TinyWang. I'm using the "application id" on the enterprise application

@SirraSneha yes the enterprise app has appropriate permissions

@user1112324 Just like what you can see in the document, the secret is necessary for DefaultAzureCredential() to get authorized by environment if we don't use CERTIFICATE.

More details about DefaultAzureCredential can be seen here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/authentication/credential-chains?tabs=dac#defaultazurecredential-overview

I dont believe that is correct @TinyWang - https://andrewmatveychuk.com/how-to-authenticate-to-azure-with-managed-identities-from-non-azure-servers/

The link shared a workaround to use Azure Arc so that in a non-Azure server we can still use managed identity. According to the error message, I have 2 ideas for it, the first is using ManagedIdentity parameter in DefaultAzureCredential like new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = "userManagedIdentityClientId" }, if it doesn't work, then maybe User assigned managed identity is not supported means users managed identity is not supported and we might need to use System-assigned managed identity.

System-assigned: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview#managed-identity-types   In the meantime, if you prefer to use Managed Identity to make your app authorized, then you don't need to set any environment. Sorry for the post above, I considered that you are trying to use environment vairble, but  in fact you are trying to use managed identity. Pls kindly let me know whether my last comment helped or not. Thanks in advance.

Im happy to use the system-assigned identity in the AZURE_CLIENT_ID but that doesnt work either. I looked up the "principalid" for the server, and added that to AZURE_CLIENT_ID but it doesnt work.

May I know who told you or which document told you to use system-assigned identity in AZURE_CLIENT_ID? This is different with my knowledge about DefaultAzureCredential. In the link I shared above about "More details", we could see that authorizing via environment varible and Managed identity is different, and they are in different steps within the whole authorizing flow. That's why I shared DefaultAzureCredentialOptions to use Managed Identity for authorization..... Pls correct me if I misunderstand it.

In the meantime, Envrionement Variable already solved your issue, and you are not hosting your app in Azure environement, why you insist on using Managed Identity even if it requires you to use Azure Arc additionally.

@user1112324 May I know whether there's any update on this question?

Doing what @andrew suggested below worked


Remove the "AZURE_CLIENT_ID + AZURE_TENANT_ID" from your environment variables so the Azure Identity client falls back to using system-assigned managed identity
Check if the system-assigned managed identity of your Arc-enabled server has proper access to your Key Vault.


Yes that worked really nicely for the VM's. I have some dockers on a linux box and they took a lot more work to see the IMDBS/Identity endpoints etc
